# jquery hide height

Tags: jquery, height, hide

why is the height value of the test div the same before and after the hide animation?

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $("#test").hide("slow", function() {  
       alert($("#test").height());  
   });
});

<div id="test">
    test
    <br />
    test
    <br />
    test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure on how the hide() animation works exactly, but if it does change the stlye-size of the element to achieve the shrinking effect, it probably reverts that to the original size after the animation is done.

The way jQuery *really* hides things is by setting one of the css styles which hides an element (I think it just sets display: none;).  The animation is just some fancy effects that don't really permanently change the element.

Comment: the animation is provided by a callback calling the effect library prior to hide()

Comment: Thanks for the anwser i guess i'll manually set the height to 0 after the animation is done.

Comment: you can do $("#test").hide("slow", function() { alert($("#test").height());  }).height(0);

Answer (score 1):

Hide() function only hides the div, it doesn't modify the height. Only adds a style="display: none;" to the element.

Answer (score 0):

you can write in the callback `style.height=' ';`